# App freezes on launch screen when installed from xcode 10.1 to iOS 12+

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode10

When I install the applications from Xcode 10.1 to iPad(iOS 12.1), apps freeze on the launch screen. Applications work fine with the iPads which have iOS version lower than 12.
I am facing this issue since i updated Xcode to 10.

Does anyone know how to fix this issue?

Comment: If you look in the log that shows in Xcode's device window, does it give any information at the time of the freeze?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am answering this question to help others who are experiencing this issue.

If you use a distribution certificate to install the app on the device with Ad-hoc provisioning profile or in-house provisioning profile app freezes on the launch screen. Even if app launches you will not get the logs in Xcode.

Following are the steps to handle this issue:

1. Create a new scheme
2. Edit this scheme and on left side select "Run"
3. For executable select "Ask on Launch"
   [image]

Use this scheme to install the app on the device. It will ask to select the executable file to launch. Select the executable file name of your app and it will launch the app on the device. You also see the logs in the Xcode.

Comment: This is happening to me in Xcode 12.1 on iOS14 and your fix works for that.

Comment: @Brett please upvote then :)

Comment: Already did back in Nov 2020  :-)

Comment: Interesting. I use a development profile (automatically managed by Xcode), but it's still happening for me. Xcode 13.4.1 and iOS 16. Does anyone figure out why it's happening?