# App freezes on launch screen when on device but works fine on simulator

Tags: ios, xcode, freeze, xcode11, launch-screen

I went back to an app I had not touched for a couple of months. However when installing and launching it on the device (iPhone X), it freezes on the launch screen.

Here is what is displayed in the console :

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/GTMSessionFetcher.framework/GTMSessionFetcher
  Referenced from: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/7ECE2655-24A5-4B69-8B99-4294C970E67F/Bangos Noir.app/Bangos Noir
  Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/7ECE2655-24A5-4B69-8B99-4294C970E67F/Bangos Noir.app/Frameworks/GTMSessionFetcher.framework/GTMSessionFetcher: code signature invalid for '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/7ECE2655-24A5-4B69-8B99-4294C970E67F/Bangos Noir.app/Frameworks/GTMSessionFetcher.framework/GTMSessionFetcher'

    /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/7ECE2655-24A5-4B69-8B99-4294C970E67F/Bangos Noir.app/Frameworks/GTMSessionFetcher.framework/GTMSessionFetcher: code signature invalid for '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/7ECE2655-24A5-4B69-8B99-4294C970E67F/Bangos Noir.app/Frameworks/GTMSessionFetcher.framework/GTMSessionFetcher'

    /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/7ECE2655-24A5-4B69-8B99-4294C970E67F/Bangos Noir.app/Frameworks/GTMSessionFetcher.framework/GTMSessionFetcher: stat() failed with errno=1
    /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/7ECE2655-24A5-4B69-8B99-4294C970E67F/Bangos Noir.app/Frameworks/GTMSessionFetcher.framework/GTMSessionFetcher: code signature invalid for '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/7ECE2655-24A5-4B69-8B99-4294C970E67F/Bangos Noir.app/Frameworks/GTMSessionFetcher.framework/GTMSessionFetcher'

    /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/7ECE2655-24A5-4B69-8B99-4294C970E67F/Bangos Noir.app/Frameworks/GTMSessionFetcher.framework/GTMSessionFetcher: stat() failed with errno=1
(lldb)
```

Moreover here is the log from the debug navigator :

```
dyld`__abort_with_payload:
    0x100e8f5dc <+0>:  mov    x16, #0x209
    0x100e8f5e0 <+4>:  svc    #0x80
->  0x100e8f5e4 <+8>:  b.lo   0x100e8f600               ; <+36>
    0x100e8f5e8 <+12>: stp    x29, x30, [sp, #-0x10]!
    0x100e8f5ec <+16>: mov    x29, sp
    0x100e8f5f0 <+20>: bl     0x100e8dbe8               ; cerror_nocancel
    0x100e8f5f4 <+24>: mov    sp, x29
    0x100e8f5f8 <+28>: ldp    x29, x30, [sp], #0x10
    0x100e8f5fc <+32>: ret    
    0x100e8f600 <+36>: ret
```

However, the app runs just fine on a simulator.

I found a possible solution here

> https://stackoverflow.com/a/60257204/10213202

But it does not work for me.

PS : app name is Bangos Noir.

Comment: Same as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45685904/i-cant-fix-dyld-library-not-loaded-rpath-gtmsessionfetcher-framework-gtmsess and others.

Comment: gtm-session-fetcher was not loaded at runtime.
Please clean your build and delete derived data and run again. This has happened to me too.

Comment: I did clean the build and I deleted the derived data. the app still won't run on my device.

Comment: I also tried the method mentioned at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45685904/i-cant-fix-dyld-library-not-loaded-rpath-gtmsessionfetcher-framework-gtmsess it does not work.